# Count phrases in a string in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently grabbing a HTML page and counting the single words on the page using:

```
$page_content = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;

$word_array = array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtolower($page_content));
```

Which works great for counting single words.

But I'm trying to count phrases of up to about 3 words.

For example:

```
$string = 'the best stack post';
```

The count would return:

```
the = 1
best = 1
stack = 1
post = 1
```

I need phrases to pulled out of the string, so a three word phrase from that string could be:

```
the best stack = 1
best stack post = 1
```

I hope that makes sense!

I've searched but cannot find any way to do this in PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the phrases the same each time? Always 3 words?

Comment: if the phrases are always (3 words), you can divide the phrase by 3.

Comment: `str_word_count()` works well for me no matter how many words a phrase have it gives me correct results

Comment: What's a phrase in this context?

Comment: I've edited the answer for more clarity, I hope!

Comment: So, you want all groups of three words? Or groups of one, two, or three words?

Comment: Do you reset the phrase if you encounter a full-stop? For example would "Hello world. Second sentence." contain any 3 word phrases?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Yes I want all groups of three words.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's two steps to this solution.

1. There's a function that gets all 3 word phrases from a string (ignoring any full-stops)
2. The main function will use the previous function on every sentence (terminated by `.`).

Here's the code:

```
function threeWords($string) {
      $words = array_values(array_filter(preg_split("!\W!",$string))); //Split on non-word characters. Not ideal probably since it will count "non-hyphenated" as 2 words. 
      if (count($words) < 3) { return []; }
      $phrases = [];
      for ($i = 2;$i < count($words);$i++) {
           $phrases[] = $words[$i-2]." ".$words[$i-1]." ".$words[$i];
      }
      return $phrases;
}

$page_content = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
$text = strip_tags(strtolower($page_content));
$sentences = explode(".",$text);
$phrases = [];
foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
   $phrases = array_merge($phrases,threeWords(trim($sentence)));
}
$count = array_count_values($phrases);
print_r($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is get the page content and remove html tags. Then explode the text by the typical phrase separator, which is the dot (.). Now you have an array of single phrases, for which you can count single words:

```
$page_content = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
$text = strip_tags(strtolower($page_content));

$phrases = explode(".", $text);

$count = 0;
foreach ($phrases as $phrase) {
    if (str_word_count($phrase) >= 3) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!     Getting an error though: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just calling `str_word_count` suffices, I edited the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
// Split the string into sentences on the appropriate punctuation marks
// and loop over the sentences
foreach (preg_split('/[?.!]/', $string) as $sentence) {

    // split the sentences into words (remove any empty strings with array_filter)
    $words = array_filter(explode(' ', $sentence));

    // take the first set of three words from the sentence, then remove the first word,
    // until the sentence is gone.
    while ($words) {
        $phrase = array_slice($words, 0, 3);

        // check that the phrase is the correct length            
        if (count($phrase) == 3) {

            // convert it back to a string
            $phrase = implode(' ', $phrase);

            // increment the count for that phrase in your result
            if (!isset($phrases[$phrase])) $phrases[$phrase] = 0;
            $phrases[$phrase]++;
        }
        array_shift($words);
    }
}
```