# How to break a large string of text into groups of 2 & 3 words in php

Tags: php

I've got a very large string of text (5000 words).

I need to split it into groups of 2 and 3 words.

I want to take the group of 2 or 3 and store it in an Array as the key.

How do I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Split by word and then take chucks from the array?

Comment: Isn't this the same thing you asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815485/count-phrases-in-a-string-in-php?

Comment: Related, I didn't think posting this in the same thread would help the subject clarity!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

As you've surmised, a combination of explode() and array_chunk() would do for simple cases.

```
$chunks = array_chunk(explode(" ",$text),2);
```

You could use rand() as well to make "2 or 3" true... :-)

Comment: Awesome! So when it's chunked how do I access the 3 parts as one?